# Hide & Show password field in view, with Omniauth and facebook login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, passwords

Good evening all!

I'm having a bit of an issue, which i'll explain after some context!

Gems involved:
Devise, Omniauth, Omniauth-facebook

I've set up omniauth alongside devise, to allow users of my site to login/register via facebook, it works perfectly.
Along side this I also have a regular sign up page in which users can enter a username, email and password to register to the website.

The issue comes when a user wishes to edit their information once they are registered - via the Edit view. I want to hide the password fields for Facebook registered users (as they of course have no password), leaving only Name and Email (for now), but have the password fields show for Regular registered users so they can change their passwords.

In the mean time I have managed to by-pass the "enter confirmation password" forced by devise, so Facebook users don't need to enter a confirmation password (as one doesn't exist) where regular users do. 
Achieved by the following in user.rb:

```
def update_with_password(params, *options)
 if encrypted_password.blank?
 update_attributes(params, *options)
else
 super
 end
end
```

To solve my password problem, I have attempted adding the following to my user.rb:

```
   def password_required?
    (authentications.empty? || !password.blank?) && super
   end
```

Followed by the following in my devise\registrations\edit.html.erb:

```
<% if @user.password_required? %>
  <%= f.input :current_password, :hint => "We need your current password to confirm any changes", :required => false %>
 <h5>Change your password?</h5>
  <%= f.input :password, :autocomplete => "off", :hint => "Enter a new password above,      leave Password blank if you do not wish to change it", :required => false %>
  <%= f.input :password_confirmation, :required => false %>
<% end %>
```

After following elements of this guide: http://www.orhancanceylan.com/rails-twitter-and-facebook-authentications-with-omniauth-and-devise/.

The password inputs are hidden by the above code, however it is hidden for both Facebook registered users and regular registered users, so I'm afraid I'm at a loss!

Please let me know if there's anything else I should've posted to help narrow down the issue, and apologies if I have missed posting anything related.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`password_required?` is intended to be a check for whether to validate the presence & confirmation of password on save, only. Here's the definition of the method, at lib/devise/models/validatable:50-55

```
  # Checks whether a password is needed or not. For validations only.
  # Passwords are always required if it's a new record, or if the password
  # or confirmation are being set somewhere.
  def password_required?
    !persisted? || !password.nil? || !password_confirmation.nil?
  end
```

Note the "For validations only." comment.

You should use a different check for whether the user is an oauth user or an e-mail/password user. For example:

in app/models/user.rb

```
def oauth_user?
  authentications.present?
end
```

Then just check directly whether `@user.oauth_user?` in your view.

Comment: Ahh, I see exactly what I was doing now!

That worked perfectly for what I wanted to do! Thank you very much good sir :)

Comment: `authentications.present?` will do a SQL count. In this case, it doesn't really affect performance (since it probably will only be called in a user's profile page) but this could still be improved. In fact, that method isn't even needed. Instead of doing `@user.password_required?`, simply check if the user has a password! `encrypted_password` is the name of the field in the database where the password is stored, automatically created by Devise. So you can use `@user.encrypted_password?` to ask if the attribute is set or not.